# How to get update current location in mainactivity instead of last location by using GPS?

Tags: android-studio, gps, location, on-location-changed

This is the gps class for mainactivity to call track user location

```
public class TrackGPS extends Service implements LocationListener{
    private final Context mContext;

       boolean checkGPS = false;

    boolean checkNetwork = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location loc;
   public double latitude;
    public double longitude;


    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1;


    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public TrackGPS(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        getLocation();
    }
```

This is the get the location code for longitude and latitude

```
    private Location getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            checkGPS = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            checkNetwork = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

This is to check whether network and gps is turn on ?

```
            if (!checkGPS && !checkNetwork) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Service Provider Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (checkNetwork) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    try {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            loc = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        }

                        if (loc != null) {
                            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(SecurityException e){

                        Toast.makeText(TrackGPS.this, "please turn on gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (checkGPS) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (loc == null) {
                    try {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            loc = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (loc != null) {
                                latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                                longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return loc;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (loc != null) {
            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }


 public double getLatitude() {
        if (loc != null) {
            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);


        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Not Enabled");

        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you wants to turn On GPS");


        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });


        alertDialog.show();
    }


    public void stopUsingGPS() {

//        if (locationManager != null) {
//
//          locationManager.removeUpdates(TrackGPS.this);
//      }

        try {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(TrackGPS.this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("PERMISSION_EXCEPTION","PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
        }
   }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

how to get the location updated longitude and latitude from mainactivity when every time is change ?

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (loc != null) {
            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            longitude = loc.getLongitude();

        }


    }


}
```

this is call in main activity to get the location

```
public void getLocation() {


        gps = new TrackGPS(econtacts.this);


        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {


            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();


           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude:" + Double.toString(longitude) + "\nLatitude:" + Double.toString(latitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {

            gps.showSettingsAlert();

        }

    }
```